# RAD Studio build fails on Window 10

Tags: windows, build, c++builder, c++builder-xe8

I am using C++Builder in RAD Studio XE8 on a Windows 10 system.

If I change an application (even only changing the position of a component) and rebuild, the app works fine on the first rebuild.

But, in the *following rebuilds*, the app crashes at start with "access violation".

If I just close and reopen the project, again only the first rebuild works.

Also, if I delete the `project.ilc` file in the debug folder and rebuild, the app works fine.

Has anyone seen this behavior?

Comment: Not a real solution, disable incremental link bypass the problem.

Comment: Incremental linking is frequently problematic, it is best to just not use it at all.